# XMLHttpRequest can get data to display on webpage

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to retrieve data from a web page and then display it on my webpage, nothing fancy atm just display it so it cam be read, however I am not sure how to do this, this is what I have so far(Also sorry if I've not done the formatting properly I'm still new to this):

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<title> Night Out In Glasgow!!</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css">
<script src="pull.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
    <form action = "">
        <p><button type = "button" onclick ="getData()">Get The Data</button>
        </p>
    </form>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

This is then my JS which is in a separate file called pull.js, which I have linked to in my HTML, hope this clears up any confusion form original post.

```
    /*jslint node: true, browser: true */

    "use strict";
    /*jslint node: true, browser: true */

    "use strict";

    function getData(){
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST","http://ratings.food.gov.uk/OpenDataFiles/FHRS776en- GB.xml");
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = checkData;
        xmlhttp.send(null);
        function checkData() {
           if(xmlhttp.status == 4){   
           if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
            //We've got a response
            alert(xmlhttp.responseXML);
             }
           }
           else{
               //Somethings went wrong
               alert("Error: " + xmlhttp.status + ": " +xmlhttp.statusXML);
                  }
                }
              }
```

Comment: Your javascript needs to be in a `<script></script>` tag.

Comment: Is this for the formatting on here? If so cheers for the tip I'll keep that in mind, if its about the actual code I have them on different files and refer to the JS using <script src="pull.js"></script>

Comment: What have you tried that doesn't work? Do you know how to use Javascript to insert elements into the DOM? Or are you failing to get data back from the Ajax call? JQuery might help simplify your code if you are able to use it.

Comment: Inserting elements into the DOM I've done a bit of that but not much. I'm assuming that the AJAX is failing to the get the data however I was wondering to retrieve data from a webpage do I need to create a server or can I do it from the client?

Comment: @CallumRob - so everything after the `</body>` is actually in pull.js?  If so, I'd recommend breaking that code section off into a second code section titled **pull.js** or something, for readability purposes.  It looks like that's actual code on the page.

Comment: Edited it now, hope that clears things up

Answer (score 0):

Try it in this order:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST","...");
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = {
       if(xmlhttp.status == 4){   
       if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
       ...
};
xmlhttp.send();
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure with your case, but the same origin policy restricts contents retrieved via `XMLHttpRequest` to be accessed from a website with different origin. Go check this [StackExchange answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/16221/28637)

Comment: Do you think I would be as well using some PHP for this and then just using my AJAX to communicate with the PHP?

Comment: Why the downvote? I think this is a perfectly valid case since the OP doesn't include the headers of the HTTP responses, or any error report from the console etc. The error may not be in the app, but rather in the request itself due to this restriction

Comment: Your suggestion was correct, I don't know why you got a down vote, since I used the PHP script it has started working. Thanks